# is this legal in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

This is my function:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.on('checkcrn', function (msg) {
                socket.on('error', function(err){
                  console.log("err + " + err);
                })
                console.log("message " + msg);
            });
        });
```

What I am trying to do is calling the same socket but on different event on another event. Is this even possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a standalone version that mimics your code:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

let socket = new EventEmitter();

socket.on('checkcrn', function (msg) {
  socket.on('error', function(err){
    console.log("err + " + err);
  })
  console.log("message " + msg);
});

socket.emit('checkcrn', 'hello world #1');
socket.emit('checkcrn', 'hello world #2');
socket.emit('error', 'error #1');
```

If you run that, you will see that `err + error #1` is logged twice. Even worse: if you send more `checkcrn` messages, there will be an extra error message for each `checkcrn` message that you sent. That's because you add a new `error` listener for each `checkcrn` message.

You can fix that problem by moving the declaration of an `error` listener to the same level as the `checkcrn` listener:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('checkcrn', function (msg) {
    console.log("message " + msg);
  });

  socket.on('error', function(err){
    console.log("err + " + err);
  });

});
```

It's still the same `socket` that you are attaching the listener to.

Comment: As far as I can understand, he wants to get `error` **only** after the client has already send `checkcrn`. But you are right - this kind of thing should not be done the way it is. It's better to have some kind of socket-level variable to determine if we want the error listener to fire up or not.

Comment: If it's indirectly, then you should either revise your question, ask for better answer or simply delete all. Now people will follow this and get the bad working code (and by bad I mean not good for the thing it's needed)

Answer (score 0):

It's a good example which demonstrates a memory leakage as it is.

By assigning *event listeners* inside other *event listeners* you create new handlers on every new event has been caught (without removing them later) which is really bad.

Keep listeners on the same level and everything will be ok.

**FYI:** in case you don't need to track some kind of events, you could simply unbind this event tracking by doing `socket.removeListener('eventname', functionReference)`